# ntheorem Definition/Lemma/... ending with \dots results in no end-of-proof symbol

Tags: ntheorem, ellipsis

I would like to end `ntheorem` definition or proof with ellipsis. However, when I change the dot `.` in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[standard,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}[Test definition]
    Text.
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]
to `\dots`, `\ldots` or `\textellipsis`, e.g.:

```
\begin{Definition}[Test definition]
    Text\dots
\end{Definition}
```

I get result with to end-of-proof symbol at the end:
[image]
I cannot find the reason of this behavior. I can bypass this by using `$\dots$`, but it looks like I am ignoring the real cause. Is it possible to achieve the desired result in a more 'proper' way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `thmmarks` relies on the text ending with a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[standard,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}[Test definition]
Text\dots{}
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The package redefines `\endtrivlist` like

```
\gdef\endtrivlist{%
  \@endtrivlist{\PotEndMark{\unskip\nobreak\hfill\nobreak}}}
\gdef\@endtrivlist#1{%  % from \endtrivlist
  \if@inlabel \indent\fi
  \if@newlist \@noitemerr\fi
  \ifhmode
     \ifdim\lastskip >\z@ #1\unskip \par  %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
           \else \unskip \par \fi
     \fi
[...]
}
```

whereas the standard `\endtrivlist` has just

```
  \ifhmode\unskip \par
```

that would remove two trailing glue items (one possibly from the end-of-line and one after `\end{trivlist}`).

The redefinition is aimed to insert `\PotEndMark{\unskip\nobreak\hfill\nobreak}}` at the appropriate spot, but makes little sense as written. Anyway, this explains why a missing space or even input such as

```
\begin{Definition}Text\end{Definition}
```

will not print the mark. The mark also disappears if a blank line precedes `\end{Definition}`.